# after uninstalling extension magento admin panel is showing registry key error

Tags: php, magento

I uninstalled the magento extension, and my magento admin began showing this :error.

There has been an error processing your request

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/tmcore/observer" already exists

Trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/tmco...', false)
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('tmcore/observer')
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /var/www/clients/client1/web7/web/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

What's causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't hit us with your font size...

Comment: The code needs to be formatted. Pay special attention to typing everything correctly, as well. Make sure there is a question too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete 'maintenance.flag' file form magento root directory and it'll work.